# What is the handle in Vulkan?

Tags: memory, vulkan

What is the meaning of the word *handle* in Vulkan API? I mean, why don't we use references & in Vulkan functions?

For example why do we use `vkDeviceWaitIdle(vkDevice)` instead of `vkDeviceWaitIdle(vkDevice &)` or `vkDeviceWaitIdle(vkDevice*)`? I've seen that we pass object's handle, that's why we don't need references. But I haven't found more information about this...

Comment: "*What is the meaning of the word descriptor in Vulkan API except for a resource descriptor?*" It has no meaning besides that. And descriptors have nothing to do with C++ reference types. This question seems to be two very confused questions.

Comment: @NicolBolas I have just found out that it is not called 'descriptor' in English... Its original name is HANDLE O-O I'm sorry  In the book I'm reading 'descriptor' is marked as an English equivalent...

Comment: @FlufflePuff you should edit the question to clarify what you meant before it gets closed as nonsensical.

Answer (score 1):

The Vulkan API that you're referring to is a C-API.  Meaning you can use it with pure C applications.  C itself doesn't include the concept of references, so the API simply can't use them at all or it would be incompatible with pure C applications.

Even though you see lots of example code out there written in C++ for Vulkan, that doesn't mean the C API can use C++ features, and there's a separate `vulkan.hpp` header that contains C++ bindings for Vulkan that does make use of pass by reference where appropriate.  Bear in mind that this is simply syntactic sugar and the C++ API is simply a wrapper around the C API.

Comment: Then why don't we use VkDevice* ? Why do we need to copy the argument?

Comment: Well, for one thing, pointers aren't guaranteed to be 64 bits on every platform.  And on a 64 bit system there's no difference in cost between putting a 64 bit pointer on the stack to putting a 64 bit handle on the stack, other than if you use a pointer, it requires the receiver to then resolve that pointer into the actual value, which could have been on the stack in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

The reason for using `vkDeviceWaitIdle(vkDevice)` instead of `vkDeviceWaitIdle(vkDevice &)` is that the latter would require passing a reference to the device object, which could potentially lead to memory issues or undefined behavior if the object is deleted or modified during the execution of the function. By passing the device object as a value, we ensure that a copy of the object is created and used within the function, avoiding any potential issues with references. Additionally, passing the device object as a value is more consistent with the Vulkan API design, as most functions take objects as values rather than references.

This is related to the device handle. In Vulkan, each object has its own handle, which is a unique identifier for the object in the context of the current session. Passing a reference to the device object can lead to issues with the descriptor if the object is deleted or modified during the execution of the function. By passing the device object as a value, we ensure that a copy of the descriptor will be created and used inside the function, avoiding potential problems with references and descriptors.

Vulkan handles are always 64 bits wide, regardless of the bitness of the host system.

Comment: Non-dispatchable handles might not be unique. Dispatchable handles may be pointer size (i.e. could be 32 bits).

Comment: No, the reason references aren't used in the C API is that C doesn't have the concept of references. They're a C++ concept.  Also, using references doesn't have any implicit memory issues or undefined behavior.  The C++ bindings for Vulkan use them all over the place.

Comment: "*require passing a reference to the device object, which could potentially lead to memory issues*", the solution to that is to pass by const reference in C++, which vulkan is not. That's also not a concern, and dispatchable handles are actually pointers and thus don't follow what one would normally consider pass-by-value semantics.

Comment: @vandench does Vulkan actually *copy* the argument to take its handle?

Comment: The function call copies the *pointer* (which is just an integer, usually), it does not copy the *object*. Even if you wanted to, you wouldn't be able to copy the underlying object, as its layout isn't specified by the spec. The dispatchable objects are also allowed to store state for the driver and layers, so making them immutable would be disadvantageous.